# dts-gen: fails to find globally installed modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-definitions

I have installed dts-gen globally

`npm i -g dts-gen`

I installed the target module globally

`npm i -g jhipster-core`

When I run

`dts-gen -m jhipster-core -o`

I get the following output:

`Couldn't load module "jhipster-core". Please install it globally (npm install -g jhipster-core) and try again.`

---

I am working on a Windows 10 PC and executing the commands on the windows command prompt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Installing NPM modules globally is usually a bad idea - you will eventually get into weird situations when the globally installed version accidentally gets used instead of the version specified in some package.json file.

But in this case, the problem seems to be that "jhipster-core" requires the "chalk" module, but does not list it in package.json dependencies.

This worked for me (just run it in some empty directory):

```
npm install dts-gen jhipster-core chalk
./node_modules/.bin/dts-gen -m jhipster-core
```

Comment: Thank you - that did it. I think in addition to the missing `chalk` dependency, I was trying to run the dts-gen command within the `jhipster-core` project itself.

Comment: I tried with both a blank directory (complains about a missing package.json)  and with an npm init'd folder and still receive this error message The answer has forward slashes in the path so suggests it doesn't answer the question of Windows 10 PCs.